# How to make a script which can give several input for executing multi-step program?

Tags: linux

For example, I want to resize my partition under Ubuntu and use the command line tool: parted. Usually I need several steps to answer its questions.

```
root@intel-corei7-64:~# parted /dev/mmcblk0 resizepart 3 29000M
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/mmcblk0 appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 53420032 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
parted: invalid token: 3                                                  
Fix/Ignore? Fix                                                           
Partition number? 3                                                       
Warning: Partition /dev/mmcblk0p3 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes                                                               
End?  [3914MB]? 29000MB                                                   
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

The first command line is `parted /dev/mmcblk0 resizepart 3 29000M`
Then I answer `Fix` for its first question. Then `3` for the 2nd question. Then `Yes` for the 3rd question. Then `29000MB` for the last question.

I need to do all these steps automatically by one script, how to make such a script?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like:

```
echo -e "Fix\n3\nYes\n29000MB" | parted /dev/mmcblk0 resizepart 3 29000M
```